# Object doesn't support property or method addEventListener in Citrix Workspace

Tags: jquery, citrix

I have a `rails 5` app and I'm launching it from within a `Citrix Workspace`.
I've bundled `jQuery 3.4.1` from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js within my assets and now I'm getting this error.

[image: rix]

Comment: What IE version is that app using? You need to debug the code, your javascript code is trying to call `addEventListener` on an Object instead of an HTMLElement.

Comment: You need to use the debug tools that come with your browser. It will be in the menu system somewhere. There should be a tab showing all the logs in more detail.

Comment: are you running this on an ancient version of Internet Explorer? If so it won't work. Use a modern browser. Or if you have to, try jQuery 1.12.4, which is the last version to support IE8 and below.

Comment: @monty_lennie Any solution on this, same issue occurring for me in CITRIX workspace only. In other machine it is working.